# network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: permissions

I am running sqldeveloper on my laptop windows 8.1. When I was debuggin it asked me to give permission - by default it allowed local network and not public network.

When I run process , it give me this error message 
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '192.168.199.1', '55582' )
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1

how can I give permission since this is legitimate user and process.

Thanks

-Mahendra

Answer (score 0):

This is oracle 12c new prerequirements for debugging.
See:
http://rajeshwaranbtech.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/ora-24247-error-with-sql-developer-on.html

Comment: explain the solution here instead of using a link